# Way of searching if given date and time is within the "Availability" range or not - Google formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As a Personal task I am working with file (Google Sheet), Actually in that I need to look my plan slots are with in the availability range or not based on the given ID in column M.

Then I need to Update status of column N as below

1- Planned Inside  -Need to match the  relevant ID Number (Column N) with  shift Schedule (Table 01) date and time is with in the Daily availability (Table 02) range Then consider as Planned Inside

2 -Planned Outside - Need to match the  relevant ID Number (Column N) with  shift Schedule (Table 01) date and time is not with in the Daily availability (Table 02) range Then consider as Planned Out side. Need to Match all range but if any Plan schedule is Outside the Availability range need to consider as  Planned Outside

3. No Availability  chosen - IF Schedule ID is not available in Availability list.

[Snap Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EUfW.png)

Google File
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fV4o08nF4gA26DquCEl4P61QU2VILYOxSRcfDxB80H4/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope this video will help you to get idea about the requirements.

[Guidance Vidoe](https://www.loom.com/share/6bdd6b9ac1f542058a33e4baad286b91)

Actually its not allowed to use Google Script, So I need to develop this using only google sheet formula.

Please review and Let me know your ideas and solution for this.

Best regard
Indika

For Now I am using Let [text](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) and few other function like [SORT Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en&sjid=16817755355651570265-AP)

Comment: Explain your problem in post not in video.

Comment: So sorry on that, I am new to this, so I try to Explain in Video. Now I added all detail in the Post as well.